# vue - force reload template and then execute action

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have vue component which has `v-for` and button "add".

```
<v-text-field
    v-for="(i, item) in items"
    ref="test"
></v-text-field>

<button @click="add()">add</button>
```

and JS:

```
methods: {
    add() {
        this.items.push('');
        this.$refs['test'][this.items.length-1].focus();
    }
}
```

and I want to focus just added alement, but actually when I'm executing `focus()` method element doesn't exist - because `v-for` will upload it after method `add()` will be done.

How can I force update template and then execute this `focus` method on last element?

Comment: See if `Vue.nextTick(() => { this.$refs['test'][this.items.length-1].focus() })` works first. Reloading app just for what you need might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create yourself a little `v-focus` [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) and on `inserted` use the `el` argument passed to the directive to call `focus()` on.

```js
Vue.directive('focus', {
  inserted (el) {
    el.focus();
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    inputs: ['', '', '']
  },
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.inputs.push('')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <input v-for="(input, i) in inputs" v-focus />
  
  <button @click="add">add</button>
</div>
```